# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined" in D3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, techan.js

I'm trying to implement the Techan (d3 charts) lib into my React app.  Getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined".  "module.exports
> C:/Users/Greg/Projects/react-demos/my-react-splitter-layout/node_modules/techan/dist/techan.js:1422"

Line 1422 is:

```
heikinashi: require('./heikinashi')(indicatorMixin, accessor.ohlc, d3.min, d3.max),
```

My React js imports are:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
import * as techan from "techan"
```

I've been googling for hours.  I have tried every "fix" described [here](https://github.com/andredumas/techan.js/issues/179) but none of them work.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since the d3 chart works just fine on its own without that error, there must be some kind of collision with other dependencies of the app its being inserted into.

Comment: Couldn't find a way around this so I was forced to give up on React and go back to straight javascript.